# How to resolve WebSphere MQ Reason code 2195 related error?

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

I am getting an WebSphere MQ Reason code 2195 `MQRC_UNEXPECTED_ERROR` when I try to connect to the message flows deployed on the execution group. Can somebody please tell me what exactly does this reason code mean? Queue manager, broker , execution group.. everything is up and running and the ports are also open. I am not getting anything worthwhile on the net.
Please advise.

Answer (score 13):

The 2195 return code is a high-level exception that is hit when errors are not caught at lower levels in the code.  Very often these are generated when some external dependency such as file access or OS resources do not behave as expected and the failure cascades into WMQ.

Usually when these errors are thrown, WMQ will produce an FDC file in `{WMQ install dir}/errors` to record the event.  The FDC file tells which executable failed, the function that was executing during the failure, the environment, user ID and many other details.  These can be used by IBM to diagnose the problem but are often useful for WMQ admins as well.

As a general rule, for any WMQ error that you cannot easily diagnose, take a look in:
`{WMQ install dir}/qmgrs/{qmgr name}/errors/AMQERR01.LOG`
`{WMQ install dir}/errors/AMQERR01.LOG`
`{WMQ install dir}/errors/*.FDC`

When reporting an error, please post whether you found any error log entries or new FDC files in these locations and if so what the content of these was.  This will make it easier for respondents to to provide answers that are specific and relevant.  If you care to update your question with diagnostic info from the `errors` directories, I'll be happy to update this response in kind.

Answer (score 0):

You might encounter this code after changing your NT password, as the service tries to log on with your saved credentials.
Change the UID/pwd through the command console - 
AMQMSRVN -user \ -password

And, to be safe, in ther services menu, update the stored passwords for Services MQSeriesBrokerROL_ACB_BROKER and MQSeriesServices in properties -> LogON