# Java MQ Queue Message "Get" Completion Code 2 Reason 2195

Tags: java, ibm-mq, mq

I have a simple MQ Queue read source as bellow, but I always get error on **queue.get** instruction.
**MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2195'**
My simple source is as:

```
    MQEnvironment.hostname = "60.1.6.24";
    MQEnvironment.port = 1414;
    MQEnvironment.channel = "ServerChannel";
    MQEnvironment.userID = "mq";
    MQEnvironment.password = "mqinfotest$2014";
    MQEnvironment.CCSID = Integer.parseInt("1098");

    MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager("QMDevelop");
    int openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE | CMQC.MQOO_NO_READ_AHEAD;

    MQQueue queue = qMgr.accessQueue("SaptaQueue", openOptions);

    if (queue.getCurrentDepth() > 0) {
        MQMessage getMessage = new MQMessage();
        getMessage.clearMessage();
        queue.get(getMessage, new MQGetMessageOptions());

        String txt = getMessage.readLine();
        System.out.println("txt = " + txt);
    }

    if (queue != null)
        queue.close();
    if (qMgr != null)
        qMgr.disconnect();
```

Data read successfully but get error!!
What should I do get ride of error.
Thanks

Comment: Is there anybody out there?(Pink Floyd):)

Comment: Have you checked out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687004/how-to-resolve-websphere-mq-reason-code-2195-related-error ?

Comment: Please post full exception stack.

Comment: What version of MQ and client are you running?  We cant help unless you give details.  Any FDC?  errors in AMQERRO1.LOG?  May be http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IZ66146.  Try including the PCF jar.

Comment: Dear Friends,
I runed my client app on win8.1 64bit and use JDK8. while running I don't get except.
I get error in console window!.
My Jar lib includes
com.ibm.mq.jar
com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar
com.ibm.mq.headers.jar
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
connector.jar
What I found in \error dir an FDC file is as

Comment: PIDS 5724H7220
LVLS 7.5.0.1
Probe Id XC076001
Application Name MQM
Component xcsGetMessage
SCCS Info F:\build\slot1\p750_P\src\lib\cs\pc\winnt\amqxeimn.c,
Line Number 511
Build Date Mar  8 2013
Build Level p750-001-130308
Build Type IKAP - (Production)

Comment: UserID MUSR_MQADMIN  
Process Name C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\amqrmppa.exe  
QueueManager QMDevelop  
UserApp FALSE  
ConnId(1) IPCC 154  
ConnId(3) QM-P 362  
Last HQC 4.0.0-22432  
Last HSHMEMB 0.0.0-0  
Major Errorcode xecF_E_UNEXPECTED_RC  
Minor Errorcode xecX_E_CONV_NOT_SUP  
Probe Type MSGAMQ6118  
Probe Severity 2  
Probe Description AMQ6118: An internal WebSphere MQ error has   occurred(20006047)  
FDCSequenceNumber 3  
Arith1 536895559 20006047

Comment: Your Download-Link:AMQ5368.0.rar
http://filesave.me/file/56344/AMQ5368-0-rar.html

Answer (score -1):

IBM MQ 7.5 doesn't support Java 8. You need to use Java 5, 6, or 7 at this time:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27027462#Windows_Java_Technology_ww

You should also make sure *ALL* the MQ jar files laid down in your installation are on the classpath, not just those you expect might be used.

Comment: No difference, I tested with V6 also, same problem

Comment: I used jar files from  MQ Installed dir also. No difference

Comment: Then please post the full FDC contents in your question above (not in a comment)

Comment: Your Download-Link:AMQ5368.0.rar
http://filesave.me/file/56344/AMQ5368-0-rar.html