# MQ server Exception

Tags: exception, server, mq

While I am trying to connect to MQ server, getting the below exception.
Could anybody tell me how to resolve it.

MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2195'.

A WebSphere MQ Error occured : Completion Code 2 Reason Code 2195

An MQException occurred trying to connect to the QManager.

Thanks and Regards,

K.Teja.

Comment: I hope, post at this link will be useful to you. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687004/how-to-resolve-websphere-mq-reason-code-2195-related-error

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to telnet your remote queue manager server and port ? it may be firewall settings

```
telnet -d <MQ host IP or hostname>  <channel port>
```